# PHP Prevent URL Tampering

Tags: php, get

Im trying to find a good solution to prevent url rewriting. so far I have

```
session_start();
$userEmail = $_SESSION["email"];
$user = $_GET["user"];

if(!isset($_SESSION["email"])){
header("Location:login.php");
}

if($user !== $_SESSION["email"]){
header("Location:notes.php?user=$userEmail");
}
```

The last bit of code produces a redirect error.

Comment: Show the contents of notes.php.

Comment: The contents are irrelevant I just want to know a good method for preventing url tampering

Comment: Your best method for preventing tampering is to issue SSL client certificates *only* to people you trust not to tamper, then restrict access to notes.php so that only browsers with a valid certificate can  run the script.  Unless your session is travelling through HTTPS, there's no telling what someone with a sniffer will do with the data they see crossing the wire.  Cleartext is bad.  Don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to prevent URL tampering on this page, or `notes.php`?

Without seeing `notes.php` or any other pages, it's hard to say. But to prevent URL tampering, it's always good to check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` on sensitive pages by doing something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== "previous_page.php") {
 header("Location: error_page.php");
 session_destroy();
 exit;
}
```

But that isn't full proof, because if an attacker is on `previous_page.php` he can simply browse to the page we're trying to protect, so further protection is needed.

You could (and should) implement a token system. This is done like so:

```
$_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
```

This will generate a nice long string that is unique to the person browsing that page. The point of doing this is to pass this session variable into the next page as a `$_GET` variable, then compare the two to make sure they equal each other. This is done like so:

```
$token = $_SESSION['token'];
header("Location:notes.php?user=$userEmail&token=$token");

//...then, on notes.php:
if ($_GET['token'] !== $_SESSION['token']) {
 header("Location: error_page.php");
 session_destroy();
 exit;
}
```

However, a very clever person could bypass this. I'd suggest doing more research on "CSRF Forgery." Hope this gets you off in the right direction.

Comment: The HTTP_REFERER header is provided by the browser, and therefore cannot be trusted.  Anyone with `curl` or `wget` can fake it easily.

Comment: There are holes in almost all types of security. `HTTP_REFERER` is easily by by-passable, but it atleast stumps a few people, which increases overall protection.

Comment: I disagree.  Implementing a secure solution is the only protection.  If you know it's easily faked, why implement it at all?  Half solutions just waste time by distracting you from the real task.  You cannot trust HTTP_REFERER.  So don't, and move on to something you *can* trust.

Comment: "The checking of the HTTP referer can be used to prevent CSRF." https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: If a programmer I hired tried to implement that and call it secure, I'd find a new programmer.

Comment: If that's all he did, then yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the "URL tampering" you're trying to avoid is to only allow logged in users to access a page? If that's the case, give them either a signed cookie, or a session ID that you keep in a cookie.

If that's not what you mean, please re-phrase the question - what are you trying to stop people from doing?